# How can I set LogPipelineExecutionDetails for the current module?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'd like to be able to set `LogPipelineExecutionDetails = $True` (from [about_Eventlogs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847797.aspx)) in the .psm1 file of my module but when I run Get-Module with the module name it doesn't return anything.  Is there another way to get the PSModuleInfo object for the current module?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
get-module -list | Select Name, LogPipelineExecutionDetails
```

Edit:

To alter the property it seems that you have to load the module first, even in 4.0. Loading the module also seems to be a requirement to get the -Name parameter of Get-Module to work.

`Import-Module AppLocker
(Get-Module AppLocker).LogPipelineExecutionDetails = $True
Get-Module AppLocker | select name,logpipelineexecutiondetails`

This worked for me

Comment: It gets the result but it doesn't work when used to set the value.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought you needed to just retrieve the property. I played around with it a bit more, see revised answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've come to the same conclusion.  There's a logical split in the two parts of my module (engine and UI), so I've split it into two and do this in the .psm1 of the UI module.